# Scala runtime class generation

Tags: scala

I have generated two simple scala classes at runtime following the link https://eknet.org/main/dev/runtimecompilescala.html, Now my question, is it possible to establish relationship (oo inhertance-like) between those two classes?

Thank you

Comment: That normally happens at compile time, i.e., before you generate them, not after the fact.

Comment: Have you tried using an interpreter (`IMain`) directly? That should 'accumulate' the successive invocations, so if you defined a class `A` in request X, you should be able to write `class B extends A` in request X+1.